# How to access shared folder from spring

Tags: tomcat, jcifs, shared-directory

This might look like as a question which show poor searching but the truth is that despite my googling I have not found a direction yet.

**The context**

I am developing a web player using tomcat and spring mvc.
At this point of time I have deveoped the jsp page which search the audio calls **locally(On my PC)**. However, my plan is to retrieve my audio calls from a windows shared folder. As you might have understood at the moment I keep all my audio files in a local folder on my desktop.
I need to store million of files and the amount of data expected is around 200 TB.

**My objective**

My aims are to store all calls on a windows shared folder which I can access from spring somehow and to secure the audio data to make sure **it can be played only with my audio player**

**FYI**

The database at the moment keep the metadata of the relative audio paths.
The audio files are in opus format and should be played in a html5 audio tag.

**Summary:**

1. Which is the best technology to achieve this?
2. Is a windows shared folder the best solution?
3. Do you know how can I secure the audio data? Encrypt it in the shared folder to increase security and make sure it can be played only from my application?
4. How can I connect to a external shared folder using spring? Is JCIFS a good solution. [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/jcifs.html)?
5. How can I dynamically add the path of the the shared folder to each audio files

Hope this is not a too broad question which is against stack-overflow rules. Simply a need a direction not a full answer to each of the bullet points above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: 
This question is not related to Java or the Spring-framework.

Short answer: 
Just use a configurable path and the builtin tools for your operating system.

To answer your questions:
1.) Cannot be answered easily without detailed knowledge of number of files, network, hdd sizes and performance, raid level, and many more unknown factors. Bonus answer: using common of the shelf hardware you will be fine for simple mp3 streaming.

2.) Well perhaps not, see 1). But then again, it is most probably good enough.

3.) Short answer: Keep you systems safe. As long as your network, your building and your servers are safe, your data is safe.

4.) Use the operating system tools (a CIFS mount for Linux, an Network folder mount on Windows)

5.) Set it as a parameter in your application.

Comment: I need to store million of files and as I said they are in opus format. The amount of data expected is around 200 TB. Can you please share your thoughts after this new piece of information. Are your assumptions still valid under this scenario

Comment: It is still valid, that you should not use Java to connect the shared folders, but the native OS methods.

However since you need a rather huge NAS anyway (200 TB of space are about 50 4TB HDDs at RAID-5) and will spend quite some money on that (if you want to make good use of the big NAS and package it with matching networking equipment), you should think about hiring an administrator for the setup.

iSCSI and NFS might be valid choices, too.

Comment: To me JCIFS seems an implementation of  CIFS. Wiki: **The JCIFS SMB client library enables Java applications to remotely access shared files and directories on SMB file servers(i.e. a Microsoft Windows "share") in addition to domain, workgroup, and server enumeration of NetBIOS over TCP/IP networks. It is an advanced implementation of the CIFS protocol supporting Unicode, batching, multiplexing of threaded callers, encrypted authentication, transactions, the Remote Access Protocol (RAP), and much more.**

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use the SMB client of your operating system? If there is none, then use the tools at hand.

Comment: The reason is that the application will be installed in various heterogeneous systems. What I can do is to set up the system case by case but I think it is not very convenient and quite time consuming. Whereas if I use a java library the install could be faster and highly tested. My question is about finding the right technology not to make it working